# $(a^2+b^2)/(ab+1)$ is a perfect square.

Tags: number-theory, solution-verification

> Let $a,b\in\Bbb N$ and $ab+1\mid a^2+b^2$. Then $\frac{a^2+b^2}{ab+1}$ is a perfect square.

This is very well-known problem and this question is already posted in MSE. I saw some solution given by someone and I couldn't understand.

> Proof : Write $a^2+b^2 = k(ab+1)$. Assume $a\leq b$. Write $b = ma+n$ for some natural number $m$ and $0\leq n<a$. From $0<a\leq b$, we get $a^2+1\leq ab+1\leq b^2+1$ $\color{#0a0}{\text{so that}\ m=k}.$ Now $a^2+b^2 = a^2(k^2+1)+2kna+n^2$, and as $k(ab+1) = (kb)a+k$, $\color{#0a0}{a\mid n^2-k}$. From $k(ab+1) = k(a(ka+n)+1) = k(ka^2+an+1)$, $a^2+kna+n^2-k=0$, we have $(a^2+n^2)/(an+1) = k$. Hence, as a equation of $a,b$ : $a^2+b^2 = k(ab+1)$, a pair $(n,a)$ is a solution, $\color{#0a0}{k\ \text{is a power of some natural number of at least 
>  order}\ 2}$. Hence, $\color{#0a0}{(a^2+b^2)/(ab+1)\ \text{is a perfect square}}$.

I don't know if this is a valid proof because I didn't understand the green part. Is this a valid proof? Could you explain why the green parts came out?

Comment: @RicardoCavalcanti +1.  The author is in the best position to justify their own proof, and if they are unable to then it is likely to be bogus.

Comment: @RicardoCavalcanti Actually this was written in a board so I couldn't find the author :(

Comment: Please give a link to the posted "proof".

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/250172/when-is-fa-b-fraca2b21ab-a-perfect-square-rational-number/250300#250300

Comment: @individ I don't understand a point of that link.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn’t pass the smell test.  The last sentence before the conclusion states that $k$ is a power of some natural number of order at least $2$, which is not enough to imply it is a square (it could be a cube).  This type of magical reasoning at the very end of a proof (after all the hard lifting is usually done) is typical of invalid proofs of famous results/conjectures in my experience.

As a second point against this, the very first green claim that $m=k$ is equivalent to $\lfloor b/a \rfloor = k$.  But this is already false for $(a,b) = (8,30)$ which has $(k,m,n) = (4,3,6)$.  This is not just an isolated case: there are infinitely many counterexamples with $(a,b)=(r^3, r^5-r)$.  If the proof rests on a faulty assumption so early on, it hard to expect the rest of it to be valid, even without reading it in close detail.